# How to enable guest session in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

Recently  I have updated ubuntu 14.04, due to this activity my guest session got disabled.  I want to know how to enable the guest session

Comment: You tagged this with ubuntu-touch, but doesn't seem to have anything to do with Ubuntu on a phone? Also which login manager are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As @dobey stated, it depends on the login manager. However, I will assume that you are using the default (which is lightdm) and that you are accessing a personal computer graphically (as opposed to some server through ssh).

Use the command (or some equivalent) `gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. Assuming this file exists, it should look something like:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
allow-guest=false
```

There may be additional lines if other settings have been changed. For example, mine is:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
allow-guest=false
greeter-show-manual-login=true
greeter-hide-users=true
autologin-user=ashum02
```

Find the line beginning with `allow-guest=`. If it is commented-out (although it shouldn't be), uncomment it. Then make sure it is set to `true`.